# WSGI/APACHE - “ImportError: No module named site”

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to get a django website up and running using WSGI.  The box is running centos 5 with python 2.6.

I am attempting to use the anaconda distribution from continuum analytics installed in /usr/local/lib/anaconda/.

I built mod_wsgi with ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/lib/anaconda/bin/python/

I added the following to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

#wsgi-scripts
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/lib/anaconda/bin
WSGIScriptAlias /test /var/www/wsgi-scripts/test

<Directory "/var/www/wsgi-scripts">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

but I am getting import failures as follows:

```
[Fri Mar 08 16:44:24 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_wsgi/3.4    
Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Fri Mar 08 16:44:24 2013] [info] Server built: Feb 13 2012 22:31:42
 ImportError: No module named site
 Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
 Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
```

Could anyone point out what my issue is?

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: where would I echo $PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Run it from the command line.

Comment: ok so, I have an apache user and it is undefined for it. What should I do? Should adding it to the path or pythonpath of the user fix it?